# What's wrong with this basic iptables script to allow web and pinging?

Tags: iptables, firewall

What's wrong with this basic iptables script to allow web and pinging?

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F
iptables -L
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP
iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-port 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-port 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --destination-port 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -L -v

/sbin/iptables-save
```

When I go to a website, the pages fail to load.

Comment: Normal web client.